# Specific cell test understanding the game of life Function

Tags: java, arrays

I have game of life exercise, I wrote the whole game only remains for me to write the function that checks the cell and decides whether he lives or dies.

the code:

```
public class lifeGame1 {
public static void main(String[]args){
    gameOfLife(4, 5, 0.3);
}

public static void gameOfLife(int n, int m, double p){
    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

    // Random each matrix[i][j]
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(Math.random() < p)
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
            else
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
        } // for j
    } // for i

    System.out.println("The board is: ");
    printMatrix(matrix);

    int steps = 0;
    while(steps < m){
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[n][n];
        for(int i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < newMatrix[i].length; j++){
                newMatrix[i][j] = checkTheNewValueOfCell(matrix, i, j);
            }
        }

        matrix = newMatrix;
        System.out.println("The new board: ");
        printMatrix(matrix);

        steps++;
    } // while

}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    // Random each matrix[i][j]
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){ // for each row
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){ // print one row
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        } // for j
        System.out.println();
    } // for i
}
}
```

Cell can make the dead or make a life according to the following rules:
1. Live cell can become dead as a result of:

A. If it has a density of more than three live neighbors.

B. Solitude if it has fewer than two live neighbors.
Hence the cell life continues to be my life if and only if it has two or three    live neighbors.

2 dead cell can turn the cheek if it has exactly three live neighbors.

3. While the volume chamber has five neighbors) if Angular three (but also for work the same rules.

Code that checks the cell:

```
 private static int checkTheNewValueOfCell(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
    // check how much active neighbors
    int countActiveNeighbors = 0;
    for(int k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++){
        for(int m = j-1; m <= j+1; m++){
            if(k >= 0 && k < matrix.length && m >= 0 && m < matrix[0].length){ // אם בתחום
                if(k != i || m != j)
                    if(matrix[k][m] == 1)
                        countActiveNeighbors++;
            } // if
        } // for m
    } // for k

    if(matrix[i][j] == 1){ // pail
        if(countActiveNeighbors == 2 || countActiveNeighbors == 3)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }else{ // savil
        if(countActiveNeighbors == 3)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    }
```

I was helped by a lecturer who register their function and indeed work, but I did not realize it until the end and it's really important for me to understand it.
I do not understand the loop Four run from i-1 to i + 1 and the loop Four which run from j-1 to j + 1.
If I am in the first cell so I should get an error that the i-1 is equal to -1 and it is beyond the scope of the array does not it?

Can help writing a simple function so we can understand it better?

thank's

Comment: Inside the loop, k is set to i - 1. If i = 0 and then k = -1, then the line `if(k >= 0 ...` will fail and it will skip over the invalid index. The same applies with j and m, the loop has an `if` statement inside it to skip over -1 indexes

Answer (score 0):

You get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException only when you try to ACCESS an non-valid array index. But in the nested for loops, you have the following if statements:

```
if(k >= 0 && k < matrix.length && m >= 0 && m < matrix[0].length){ // אם בתחום
            if(k != i || m != j)
                if(matrix[k][m] == 1)
                    countActiveNeighbors++;
        } // if
```

the top if tests that k and m are within the matrix (they are both positive and less than the length/width of the matrix). The bottom if then actually accesses the array at index k,m. Since you check for valid indices before you access, you won't get an Exception

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the function to try and make it clearer. Paired with my comment hopefully it helps you understand!

```
private static int checkTheNewValueOfCell(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
    // check how much active neighbors
    int countActiveNeighbors = 0; // Neighbor count starts at 0
    for(int k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++){ // Loop from 1 before the cell to 1 after the cell
        for(int m = j-1; m <= j+1; m++){ // Loop from 1 above the cell to 1 below it
            if(k >= 0 && k < matrix.length && m >= 0 && m < matrix[0].length){ // אם בתחום // This if statement skips out of bounds in case we are on an edge cell
                if(k != i || m != j) // This if statement skips the current cell we are looking at
                    if(matrix[k][m] == 1) 
                        countActiveNeighbors++; // Finally we increment if we find a neighbor cell
            } // if
        } // for m
    } // for k
```